# What is the domain for this function involving arcsin?

Tags: trigonometry

I am not sure what the domain of $\displaystyle \arcsin \left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)$ is.

I know that the domain for $\arcsin$ is $[-1, 1]$, but how can I use this to find the domain of the function above?

Comment: To be more accurate, the function arcsin$(t)$ has domain $t\in [-1,1]$. Your function is arcsin$(t)$ where $t = x-2/3$. So you want to find values of $x$ such that $(x-2/3)\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: what values of $x$ would make $\displaystyle x - \frac{2}{3}$ be within the domain of $\arcsin$?

Comment: hmmm i see, thank you